# different between two time stamps parsed from log files in vivado

Tags: unix, csh

Parsing two log files from vivado , How do I compute the difference of time in minutes?

```
set start_time = "Wed Jun 12 15:12:30 2019"

set end_time = "Thu Jun 13 01:28:39 2019"
```

In csh how do I compute `start_time - end_time` and convert it to minutes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Linux with GNU coreutil's `date` you can use the `-d` flag to parse a date, and `+%s` to display it in seconds:

```
set start_time = "Wed Jun 12 15:12:30 2019"
set end_time   = "Thu Jun 13 01:28:39 2019"

@ diff = `date -d "$start_time" +%s` - `date -d "$end_time" +%s`

echo "Took $diff seconds"
```

With `@ varname` instead of `set varname` you can perform arithmetic.

Note the `-d` flag isn't portable to all systems, but Wikipedia tells me Vivado only runs on Windows and Linux, so I'll assume you're using Linux ;-)

---

I would also recommend against using `csh` for these sort of tasks if it can be avoided; it lacks functions, good redirection, has a weird parser, and some other issues. Bourne shell scripting is generally considered more robust, as would using Python or another "real" programming language be.